# How to merge two or more firebase projects in one javascript app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've recently asked a question on Stack overflow regarding this question, but the question closed for duplicate reason. i've tried every solution in which they suggested even in firebase docs. but it didn't work, SO that's why i've asked this yet again.

My question is that i want to merge my previous firebase projects to manage in an admin app. in firebase docs it suggests that when initializing the firebase config we must give a unique name for one of the config, and i did that but it's not reading it. so How can i merge my two separate projects in one app?

in my `firebase.js`

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSy...",
  authDomain: "admin-side.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "admin-side",
  storageBucket: "admin-side.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "5434...",
  appId: "1:543...:web:aa001...",
};

const firebaseConfig2 = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyB...",
  authDomain: "client-side.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "client-side",
  storageBucket: "client-side.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "74150...",
  appId: "1:741...:web:7614...",
};

const app = getApps().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const app2 = getApps().length
  ? getApp()
  : initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, "secondary");

const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

const db2 = getFirestore(app2);
const storage2 = getStorage(app2);

export { db, storage, db2, storage2 };
```

this is how i'm fetching it

```
import { db, db2 } from "../firebase";
import {
  collection,
  getCount,
  getDocs,
  limit,
  query,
  startAfter,
  where,
} from "firebase/firestore/lite";

export default function HomePage(){

const getData = async () => {
    const constraints = [];

    constraints.push(limit(10));

    // in db there is a collection called "blogPosts"
    // and in db2 there is a collection called "posts"

    // when i call "posts" with db2 it returns empty array.
    // when i call "blogPosts" with db it returns the value
    // and when i call "blogPosts" with db2 it returns the value from 
    // db, so in initialization it only registers the first project

    const posts = collection(db2, "posts");
    let q = query(blogs, ...constraints);

    const qSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const dataQ = qSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));

    console.log(dataQ); // this returns an empty array

    setDatas(dataQ);
    setLoader(false);

  }
}
```

in db there is a collection called "blogPosts", and in db2 there is a collection called "posts". when i call "posts" with db2 it returns empty array. when i call "blogPosts" with db it returns the value  and when i call "blogPosts" with db2 it returns the value from db, so in initialization it only registers the first project.

Comment: "*but it's not reading it*" - that's not enough debugging details to work with.  Please edit the question to describe in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.  Is there an error?  Do you have logs?  What are you observing?  I don't see any code that makes use of this configuration - that seems relevant to show as well.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson it only reads from the first project.

Comment: Please share all of the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  You don't show anything that performs a query that might fail, so we don't know how to reproduce this.  I suggest reading about how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share your code based on what you learn there.  Statements like "it doesn't work" aren't very helpful - you should be specific about what is not working compared to your expectations and share any errors or logs.

Comment: @DougStevenson okay i've added more in the question

Comment: If you aren't getting any errors and the list of documents is empty, that is Firestore definitely telling you that it just couldn't find any documents.  Since we can't see your databases, it's impossible for us to know what the problem is.

Comment: @DougStevenson there are docs in there. i even removed the first config and only initialized the second firebase project. and it works perfectly. but combining them is not displaying the second database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your init code looks unnecessarily complicated.  Just both apps a unique name and don't worry about checking `getApps()`:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "admin");
const app2 = initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, "client");
```

Comment: Thanks now it works, I've tried to give it a unique name to both, didn't work. except when i remove the `getApps()`